# iOS only received one notification, after that token is unregistered

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem when using FCM for iOS. I can only receive 1 notification per install, after that, iOS stated that my token is unregistered. Have tried to delete the token using `InstanceID.instanceID().deleteToken` and deleting instanceID using `InstanceID.instanceID().deleteID` but I still get the same unregistered token. I've also tried to send the notification from FCM console with the same result.

My code in AppDelegate:

```
let gcmMessageIDKey = "com.ucpmb"
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
    Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("delegate", "FCM reg fail")
    print("delegate", error.localizedDescription)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
    print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
    print(userInfo)

    if userInfo["module"] as! String == "pmb_voucher" {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PrePilihJurusanViewController") as! PrePilihJurusanViewController
        window?.rootViewController = centerViewController
    } else if (userInfo["module"] as! String == "pmb_result") {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let centerViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ResultTableViewController") as! ResultTableViewController
        window?.rootViewController = centerViewController
    }

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    print(notificationSettings.types.rawValue)
}   

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceive notification: UILocalNotification) {
    print("Received Local Notification:")
    print(notification.alertBody)
}
```

And for the AppDelegate extension:

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // Print message ID.
    if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }

    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
}
// [END ios_10_message_handling]

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
// [START refresh_token]
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
    print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

    // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
    // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
}
// [END refresh_token]
// [START ios_10_data_message]
// Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNs) when the app is in the foreground.
// To enable direct data messages, you can set Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
}
// [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

I'm currently using Swift 4. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have faced the same problem and my appDelegate is in same structure like yours. Why Firebase returns fcmToken as Unregistered, after its first use? Version of FirebaseInstanceID pod is 3.4.0